# java.lang.LinkageError : javax.wsdl.extensions.soap12.SOAP12HeaderFault : How to debug?

Tags: java, jboss, jvm

When deploying a war, no issues are there. At run-time, facing java.lang.LinkageError exception.

Details of exception:

```
Failed to define class javax.wsdl.extensions.soap12.SOAP12HeaderFault in Module 
"abc.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: loader 
constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) 
previously initiated loading for a different type with name 
"javax/wsdl/extensions/soap12/SOAP12HeaderFault"
```

How can I check which jars are conflicting and in which class loader?

Stack : Jboss 6, Java 7

Answer (score 0):

> A WAR deployment is considered to be a single module in JBOSS 6.
>   Classes in the WEB-INF/lib directory are treated the same as classes
>   in WEB-INF/classes directory. All classes packaged in the war will be
>   loaded with the same class loader.

So problem in **WAR** packet. You can see all dependency witth **mvn dependency:tree** command in WAR. If have two or more different version, you should delete one of them.
If there is no conflict in package, probably jboss loaded different your *SOAP12HeaderFault* version. You can exclude related dependency with **jboss-deployment-structure.xml**.

```
<deployment>
<!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies     -->
<exclusions>
    <module name="javax.wsdl" />
</exclusions>
</deployment>
```